# Crawl twitter data according to specific date

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am new to twitter Api so I don't know its use in broader sense , actually I am crawling tweets on Ghaza for my analyses and I crawl it but just as a sample from page this is what i did

```
while(page<=3):
    tweets=api.GetSearch("#Egypt",per_page=100)
```

Now I want to crawl the data but from specific dates like I want to crawl it from 2 February 2010 to 7 march 2012.Just a clue is enough but any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[query] since:2014-02-01 until:2014-02-05` ([link to docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search))

**Query operators**

```
Operator                    Finds tweets…
...
superhero since:2015-07-19  containing “superhero” and sent since date “2015-07-19” (year-month-day).
ftw until:2015-07-19        containing “ftw” and sent before the date “2015-07-19”.
...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10749700)

Comment: @AlexJolig I think this clear answer, you can do something like this

`while(page<=3):
    tweets=api.GetSearch("#Egypt since:2014-02-01 until:2014-02-05t",per_page=100)`

Answer (score 0):

I hate to bear bad news, but this sort of search isn't supported by the current [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) or the Python wrapper you're using. From the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) on the search functions:

> - The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an    index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 
>     days of Tweets.
> - You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older    than about a    week.

I wish this was possible too, but so far there's no good solution.

Comment: You want to say that this is not possible using python or Twitter Api to crawl data from specific dates , if this , than I read a lot of search papers they did the same job what I try to do.